# Primefaces get updated bean property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

In my view, I have an ajax behavior with a listener that updates a bean property and then an "oncomplete" action that executes a javascript method

This is the ajax event:

```html
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect" listener="#{backController.onRowDoubleClick}"
                                    oncomplete="openNewTab()"  />
<h:inputHidden id="hutchy" value="#{backController.productViewerUrl}" />
```

This is the bean method that should update the property:

```
public void onRowDoubleClick(final SelectEvent event) {

    RecordDTO currentRecordDTO  = (RecordDTO) event.getObject();
    setProductViewerUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + currentRecordDTO.getName());
}

public String getProductViewerUrl() {
    return productViewerUrl;
}

public void setProductViewerUrl(String productViewerUrl) {
    this.productViewerUrl = productViewerUrl;
}
```

And thereafter, the javascript method that uses the updated property:

```js
function openNewTab(){
 var url = $('#pbm\\:hutchy').val();
 var hiddenCode = "#{backController.productViewerUrl}";
 alert(url + hiddenCode);
 window.open(url, '_newtab');
}
```

The problem is that the code of Javascript doesn't get the updated value of the property (even with the hidden field), I have done some debugging after the DoubleClick event and I found that the execution doesn't pass by the getter method of the property when executing the JS (before the alert)

Does anyone have an idea? thanks in advance!

Comment: Just make sure you 'update' the part of the html where the `openNewTab` resides and it is updated. Or update the hidden input and read that input with a piece of javascript. All this has duplicates in Stackoverflow... I'lll try to find one

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<f:param name="productViewerUrl" value="#{backController.productViewerUrl}" />` then getting the value in the Bean with

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    this.productViewerUrl= params.get("productViewerUrl");
```

or binding the values in the datatable

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. This is accessing somthing serverside. OP has the problem to access the updated value on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty solution for this one, just perform an update to the hidden field after the ajax event so that the view consider the new value of the bean property like:

```
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect" listener="#{backController.onRowDoubleClick}"
                               update="form:hutchy" oncomplete="openNewTab()"  />
```